# How to make font-size smaller if a line breaks in Shopify product page?

Tags: css, shopify

The line is too long for the product description so the add to cart goes slightly down and ruins the line in the product page. I just want to make longer descriptions smaller so that they all are aligned properly. In the image, you'll see what I am talking about. I figure this needs javascript but let me know. The prntscreen link is the image (I don't know why stackoverflow isn't presenting the actual image so I added the prntscreen in case).

https://prnt.sc/17ocq60

**css rendered**

```
.grid-view-item .grid-view-item__title.h4
{
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.grid-view-item .grid-view-item__title.h4, .product-template__container .product-style-2 h1.product-single__title, #content_quickview .product-template__container .product-single__title
{
text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

**html**

```
  {% if section.settings.show_short_desc %}
  <div class="product-single__description rte" itemprop="description">
    {% assign meta = product.metafields.meta %}
    {% assign key = 'short_des' %}
    {% if meta.short_des != blank %}
    {{ meta.short_des }}
    {% elsif product.empty? %}
    {{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_description' | t }}
    {% else %}
    {{ product.description }}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if section.settings.image_banner != blank %}         
  <p class="safecheckout"> {{ section.settings.image_banner | img_url: 'master' | img_tag}}</p>
  {% endif %}

 {% if section.settings.product_details_position =="accordion" %}             
        {% include "product-tabs" %}                       
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Please post source code.

Comment: I'm not sure which code you want me to post specifically? As in the CSS? I will try my best regardless.

Comment: @AliceGirard I hope the code I've added was enough. I am not sure because the css is a bit long...

Comment: Don't post the template, post the rendered HTML. Include only the necessary CSS for the boxes so that we can reproduce your problem. What is your goal? That the boxes are the same height? Don't change font-size to achieve this, this will look highly unprofessional.

Comment: Alright, I will do that. And I want the boxes to be aligned because you can see in the prntscreen link, they are not aligned since some titles are longer than others. Aside from font size, I don't know what would be the way to absolve this because it already looks unprofessional.